# How to cycle through custom ribbon (XML) objects -VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I've been working on a reporting application in excel for my company, and in building it I decided the best way to consolidate the UI would be to create a custom ribbon.

On this custom ribbon I have a number of editboxes arranged next to one another that are used for user inputs.  These inputs are then used to build SQL statements that pull in a variety of information from relational databases. Pretty simple.

I've recieved some feedback that the users would like to click into an editbox, enter information then press the "tab" key to move to the next box, instead of clicking into the next editbox using there mouse.

I've scoured the Internet trying to find a way to adjust the UI on a custom ribbon to shortcut the tab key so it selects the next object in the ribbon.  I've had no luck! I'd love if there was a way to do this in XML, but am also proficient in VBA.

Comment: Sounds like you have a fun application. Did your looks at RonDeBruin's site - he writes a lot of excellent vba including lots about the ribbon: http://www.rondebruin.nl//win/section2.htm

Comment: I think your life will be a lot easier if you use a userform for the inputs rather than ribbon controls.